# Close a file periodically

Tags: java

I have some meta data that should be saved to a file frequently, approx every 10 seconds. As of I am using ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream, but there are frequent open and close on the file.

I am looking for something where i am periodically flush data to the file and close it automatically.

Comment: thread which u sleep for ure period of time?

Comment: is it a multithreading environment? Why isn't just stream.flush() enough?

Comment: ObjectOutputStream is not multi-threaded.  You need to close it from the thread which is writing it.

Comment: I want to maintain the integrity of the file in all cases, so want to close the file, so that next time i try to read it, there is no corruption.